# IExpress - create exe with custom icon

Tags: icons, exe, iexpress

With the help of IExpress I created an exe from a bat file and would like to set a custom icon for the exe. Is this possible?

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). It worked here with a test IExpress installer.

---

Step-by-step instructions:

1. Create your IExpress package as normal.
2. Launch Resource Hacker, then open your IExpress-generated executable.
3. In the *Action* menu, choose *Replace Icon …*
4. Open the file that contains the icon you want to use, then click *Replace*.
5. Save the file in Resource Hacker. This will get you two files:

   - Your new file: `package.exe`
   - Your original file: `package_original.exe`
6. If the icon for `package.exe` looks wrong on your computer, this is expected behaviour due to the old icon being cached by Explorer. To clear the icon cache, you can execute:

   ```
   ie4uinit.exe -show
   ```

   (This will only be a problem on the computer that you used to edit the file; other computers should show the correct icon straight away.)

Comment: Old discussion but, could you elaborate on how one would do this?

Comment: Sure, I added steps. Also found an interesting issue with the Explorer icon cache preventing the change from being immediately seen. I recorded a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QD1xJjhEypg) of me doing it, in case that helps.

Comment: Really appreciate you following up on this **and** not being condescending. Breaking all the stack exchange molds, Bravo! Thanks!

Comment: No problem – honestly, it's what I should have written in the first place. I'm grateful for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a shortcut of the exe file and then set a custom icon to it.